# Angular same page navigation param refresh workaround- any hidden traps in this solution?

Tags: angular

I have a date input field on html page:

```
<h2>The following meetings are taking place on: <input type="date"
      [(ngModel)]="selectedDate" name="selectedDate" (change)="dateChanged()"/></h2>
```

and I am navigating to refresh the page to load relevant data in the ts file.

```
dateChanged(){
    this.router.navigate(['calendar'],{queryParams : {date: this.selectedDate}});
    //this.loadBookings();
  }
```

the relevant part of ts file:

```
export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit{

  selectedDate!: string;
  bookings!: Array<Booking>;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService,
              private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute){}

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(
      (params) => {
        const date = params['date'];
        if(date){
          this.selectedDate = date;
        } else {
          this.selectedDate = formatDate(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'en-GB');
        }
      }
    );
    this.loadBookings();

  }

  loadBookings(){
    this.dataService.getBookings(this.selectedDate).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.bookings = data;
      }
    );
  }
```

I have encountered the problem where navigator is not refreshing the page when only parameter changes(and not running the OnInit() method), and solved it by taking the part of populating the bookings array out into separate method, and calling it once again on navigation (the line commented out in this example).
This solves the problem, and page is behaving as I want it to.

The question is:  Am I doing something horrible which shoudnt be done, and if yes, for what reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is true that if the route does not change, then the component also remains alive. From what I see, you are not calling `loadBookings` inside the subscription, but after it. This is the reason why the data is not loaded again without a helper function call inside `dateChanged` which is commented out now.

Extracting loading bookings into a separate method is good, so quick fix would be:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.queryParams.subscribe(
    (params) => {
      const date = params['date'];
      if(date){
        this.selectedDate = date;
      } else {
        this.selectedDate = formatDate(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'en-GB');
      }
      
      // I moved function call here, inside the subscription handler
      this.loadBookings(); 
    }
  );
}
```

But in general, I would give a few more tips on how to make this class better and more angular-way. I have commented on the changes.

```
import { map, tap, switchMap } from "rxjs/operators";

export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit {
  // leave this variable as it is, it will only be used by the form
  selectedDate!: string;

  /**
   * convert the bookings variable into an observable. 
   * it is customary to add a dollar to the end of the variable name, but this is optional. 
   * 
   * we have created a pipeline that `queryParams` passes through, 
   * first being converted to a string using `map`. 
   * then there is an side effect to save in the field using `tap`. 
   * then we pass the string to another pipeline (switchMap). 
   * in fact, this is also a transformation, like map, but asynchronous. 
   * 
   * that is, instead of imperatively describing how and where the data should go, 
   * we just painted the pipeline, which we can now easily use. 
   * 
   * to use the pipeline, you just need to add the async pipe. instead:
   * <div *ngFor="let booking of bookings">{{ booking }}</div>
   * 
   * use:
   * <div *ngFor="let booking of bookings$ | async">{{ booking }}</div>
   *                                     ~~~~~~~~~
   */
  bookings$: Observable<Booking[]> = this.route.queryParams.pipe(
    map((params) => params.date ? params.date : formatDate(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd", "en-GB")),
    tap((date) => (this.selectedDate = date)),
    switchMap((date) => this.dataService.getBookings(date))
  );

  constructor(
    private dataService: DataService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // this function is no longer needed, but may be useful for other purposes
  }

  // everything is fine here, but we remove the `loadBookings` function call
  dateChanged() {
    this.router.navigate(["calendar"], {
      queryParams: { date: this.selectedDate },
    });
  }

  // this function is no longer needed, remove
  /* loadBookings(){
    this.dataService.getBookings(this.selectedDate).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.bookings = data;
      }
    );
  } */
}
```

This version of the code is more declarative, short and concentrated. It reads faster and better explains the logic. It also allows you not to [worry about unsubscribing](https://www.learmoreseekmore.com/2021/11/why-we-have-to-unsubscribe-an-observable-in-angular-application.html). You can learn more about rxjs operators and observables [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) or [here (visually)](https://rxmarbles.com/#map).

Comment: Big thanks for the answer. Just to make sure I understood, in my own words:  initial code was not working as expected because I called loadBookings() inside OnInit, which is not running again(because component stays alive), instead of inside a subscription which remains listening and will run on change of the parameter.  As for the second part, thanks for pointing me in that direction, will need to read up on that.

Comment: Yep, everything is right